# Solr - Not Getting Results When searching

Tags: solr, lucene

I am having trouble with Solr 8.5.2 when providing a word in a query. It's fine when the query is *:*. But when I put in a word, it does not hit any document.

Here is my schema.xml config.

```
<field name="quoteid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="quotenumber" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="formdata" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="creationtimeintickssinceepoch" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Here is a sample document. (FormData field is actually a Json string, as you notice)

```
{
        "quoteid":"466f4dea-XXXX-443c-b1e4-XXXXXXX",
        "quotenumber":"NAAAAA",
        "creationtimeintickssinceepoch":15927195449809739,
        "formdata":"{\"formModel\": {\"SomeProperty0\":\"somevalue\",\"SomeProperty1\":\"somevalue\",\"SomeProperty2\":\"somevalue\"}"...blahblahblah here,
        "_version_":1670089165635584000}
```

I tried entering NAAAAA, no results. I tried 'SomeProperty1', no results too.

Comment: What's your actual query? If you're not giving any field names in your query or using `edismax` with the `qf` argument, the default search field is used (usually named `_text_`). You probably want to try to query with `quotenumber:NAAAAA` to get hits in the `quotenumber` field.

Comment: You're right!  @MatsLindh please move your comment to answer, so that I can accept it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not giving any field names in your query or using `dismax` or `edismax` with the `qf` argument, the default search field is used (usually named `_text_` - this could be configured in your schema, but is usually given as `df` with the default query handler).

You'll need to include your field name when you're querying other fields - `quotenumber:NAAAAA` to get hits in the `quotenumber` field.